# Make bootstrap carousel indicators non clickable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using tweeters bootstrap [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), and I don't want my users to be able to switch slides, I want to switch slides according to my own logic. I already removed the controls completely, but I still want to show the slide indicators.

How can I do that?

A solution in angular would be preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: are you referring to [tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) or the [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) - they're two different components in bootstrap.

Comment: @allicarn The Carousel

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom template to use for the Carousel using the `template-url` attribute. Copy the default template and remove the elements and events you don't need.

The default template:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel" ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()">
  <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
  <a role="button" href class="left carousel-control" ng-click="prev()" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
  </a>
  <a role="button" href class="right carousel-control" ng-click="next()" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">next</span>
  </a>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index" ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }" ng-click="select(slide)">
      <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

And the edited version, with the left and right buttons removed and passive page indicators:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()" class="carousel" ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()">
  <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
  <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index" ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }">
      <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Create a new .html file (or use the [template cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)) containing the above markup and add `template-url="[your file].html"` to your `<uib-carousel>` element.